# Ejecutar función al hacer click en button

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un button que al hacer click sobre el comienza a reproducir música. Al hacer clic, cambio la clase del button para que aparezca el play o el pause, pero el problema es que la música se reproduce si hago clic en cualquier parte de la página, no solamente en el botón.

Este es el código y no sé donde estoy fallando.

```
<button id="playAudio" class="play-button"></button>

<audio id="audio" style="display:none" class="radio" controls="" src="audio.mp3" autoplay="" controlslist="nodownload" class="i-amphtml-fill-content"></audio>

<script>
document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  if(this.className == 'pause'){
    this.className = "play-button";
    this.innerHTML = ""
    audio.pause();
  }else{
    this.className = "pause";
    this.innerHTML = "";
    audio.play();
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: No tienes algun audio.play en alguna otra parte del codigo?

Comment: Si, lo tengo como oculto, con display: none. Edito y lo pongo.

Comment: Copie tu código y me funciona bien, quizás falta algún extracto de código mas? O quisas cuando te refieres que la musica se reproduce de todas formas por el atributo `autoplay` de la etiqueta `<audio>` este atributo hace que se reproduzca automáticamente el audio

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de que puedas reproducir el error en algún editor de texto online?

Comment: Pues no se... he puesto autoplay="0" y autoplay="false" y sigue pasando...

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a hacer un onclick() en vez de un addEventListener():

---

```html
<button id="playAudio" class="play-button" onclick="cancion()"></button>

<audio id="audio" style="display:none" class="radio" controls="" src="audio.mp3" autoplay="" controlslist="nodownload" class="i-amphtml-fill-content"></audio>
```

```js
<script>

function cancion() {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
if(this.className == 'pause') {
    this.className = "play-button";
    this.innerHTML = ""
    audio.pause();
} else {
    this.className = "pause";
    this.innerHTML = "";
    audio.play();
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: agrega el código donde debe ir.